# Are Java Request samplers as accurate as SOAP or HTTP samplers in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

Are Java Request samplers as accurate as SOAP or HTTP samplers in jmeter? For example, I run a java request sampler which reads from a csv file and handles entries in the file through code. This causes 0 throughput in the results. 
However, when I use HTTP or SOAP samplers I get higher throughput since the entries of the csv file are handled one at a time through Jmeter not through the java code.
Any clues on how to solve this "inaccuracy" in the Java sampler results? 
Related to this question is: if I use the Java Request Sampler Test class to merely call a static method in another java class. Is that a good practice or the whole logic should be inside the runTest method?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Java Request Sampler is pretty much alike any other sampler.

Make sure that you invoke `sampleStart()` and `sampleEnd()` methods at the beginning and in the end of your test.

See **Java Request** section of [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for example Java Request Sampler source code.